# OpenGL Programmable Pipeline Point Lights

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, lighting

Since built-in uniforms such as `gl_LightSource` are now marked as deprecated in the latest versions of the OpenGL specification, I am currently implementing a basic lighting system (point lights right now) which receives all the light and material information through custom uniform variables.

I have implemented the light attenuation and specular highlights for a point light, and it seems to be working good, apart from a position glitch: I'm manually moving the light, altering its position along the X axis. The light source however (judging by the light it casts upon the square plane below it) doesn't seem to move along the X axis, but, rather, diagonally, on both the X and Z axes (possibly Y too, though it's not entirely a positioning bug).

Here's a screenshot of what the distortion looks like (the light is at -35, 5, 0, Suzanne ist at 0, 2, 0:
[image: This is obviously distorted]:

It looks OK when the light is at 0, 5, 0:
[image: This looks fine]

According to the OpenGL specification, all the default light computations take place in **eye coordinates**, which is what I'm trying to emulate here (hence the multiplication of the light position with the vMatrix). I am using just the view matrix, since applying the model transformation of the vertex batch being rendered to the light doesn't really make sense.

If it matters, all the plane's normals are pointing straight up - 0, 1, 0.

(Note: I fixed the issue now, thanks to msell and myAces! The following snippets are the corrected versions. There's also an option to add spotlight parameters to the light now (d3d style ones))

Here's the code I'm using in the **vertex shader**:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform mat4 vMatrix;

uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform vec3 vLightPosition;
uniform vec3 spotDirection;
uniform bool useTexture;

uniform bool    fogEnabled;
uniform float   minFogDistance;
uniform float   maxFogDistance;

in vec4 vVertex;
in vec3 vNormal;
in vec2 vTexCoord;

smooth out vec3     vVaryingNormal;
smooth out vec3     vVaryingLightDir;
smooth out vec2     vVaryingTexCoords;
smooth out float    fogFactor;

smooth out vec4     vertPos_ec;
smooth out vec4     lightPos_ec;
smooth out vec3     spotDirection_ec;

void main() {
    // Surface normal in eye coords
    vVaryingNormal = normalMatrix * vNormal;

    vec4 vPosition4 = mvMatrix * vVertex;
    vec3 vPosition3 = vPosition4.xyz / vPosition4.w;

    vec4 tLightPos4 = vMatrix * vec4(vLightPosition, 1.0);
    vec3 tLightPos  = tLightPos4.xyz / tLightPos4.w;

    // Diffuse light
    // Vector to light source (do NOT normalize this!)
    vVaryingLightDir = tLightPos - vPosition3;

    if(useTexture) {
        vVaryingTexCoords = vTexCoord;
    }

    lightPos_ec = vec4(tLightPos, 1.0f);
    vertPos_ec = vec4(vPosition3, 1.0f);

    // Transform the light direction (for spotlights) 
    vec4 spotDirection_ec4 = vec4(spotDirection, 1.0f);
    spotDirection_ec = spotDirection_ec4.xyz / spotDirection_ec4.w; 
    spotDirection_ec = normalMatrix * spotDirection;

    // Projected vertex
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vVertex;

    // Fog factor
    if(fogEnabled) {
        float len = length(gl_Position);
        fogFactor = (len - minFogDistance) / (maxFogDistance - minFogDistance);
        fogFactor = clamp(fogFactor, 0, 1);
    }   
}
```

And this is the code I'm using in the **fragment shader**:

```
#version 330

uniform vec4 globalAmbient;

// ADS shading model
uniform vec4 lightDiffuse;
uniform vec4 lightSpecular;
uniform float lightTheta;
uniform float lightPhi;
uniform float lightExponent;

uniform int shininess;
uniform vec4 matAmbient;
uniform vec4 matDiffuse;
uniform vec4 matSpecular;

// Cubic attenuation parameters
uniform float constantAt;
uniform float linearAt;
uniform float quadraticAt;
uniform float cubicAt;

// Texture stuff
uniform bool useTexture;
uniform sampler2D colorMap;

// Fog
uniform bool    fogEnabled;
uniform vec4    fogColor;

smooth in vec3  vVaryingNormal;
smooth in vec3  vVaryingLightDir;
smooth in vec2  vVaryingTexCoords;
smooth in float fogFactor;
smooth in vec4  vertPos_ec;
smooth in vec4  lightPos_ec;
smooth in vec3  spotDirection_ec;

out vec4 vFragColor;

// Cubic attenuation function
float att(float d) {
    float den = constantAt + d * linearAt + d * d * quadraticAt + d * d * d * cubicAt;

    if(den == 0.0f) {
        return 1.0f;
    }

    return min(1.0f, 1.0f / den);
}

float computeIntensity(in vec3 nNormal, in vec3 nLightDir) {

    float intensity = max(0.0f, dot(nNormal, nLightDir));
    float cos_outer_cone = lightTheta;
    float cos_inner_cone = lightPhi;
    float cos_inner_minus_outer = cos_inner_cone - cos_outer_cone;

    // If we are a point light
    if(lightTheta > 0.0f) {
        float cos_cur = dot(normalize(spotDirection_ec), -nLightDir);
        // d3d style smooth edge
        float spotEffect = clamp((cos_cur - cos_outer_cone) / 
                                cos_inner_minus_outer, 0.0, 1.0);
        spotEffect = pow(spotEffect, lightExponent);
        intensity *= spotEffect;
    }   

    float attenuation = att( length(lightPos_ec - vertPos_ec) );
    intensity *= attenuation;

    return intensity;
}

/**
 *  Phong per-pixel lighting shading model.
 *  Implements basic texture mapping and fog.
 */
void main() {       
    vec3 ct, cf;
    vec4 texel;
    float at, af;

    if(useTexture) {
        texel = texture2D(colorMap, vVaryingTexCoords); 
    } else {
        texel = vec4(1.0f);
    }

    ct = texel.rgb;
    at = texel.a;

    vec3 nNormal = normalize(vVaryingNormal);
    vec3 nLightDir = normalize(vVaryingLightDir);

    float intensity = computeIntensity(nNormal, nLightDir); 
    cf = matAmbient.rgb * globalAmbient.rgb + intensity * lightDiffuse.rgb * matDiffuse.rgb;    
    af = matAmbient.a * globalAmbient.a + lightDiffuse.a * matDiffuse.a;

    if(intensity > 0.0f) {
        // Specular light
        //  -   added *after* the texture color is multiplied so that
        //      we get a truly shiny result
        vec3 vReflection = normalize(reflect(-nLightDir, nNormal));
        float spec = max(0.0, dot(nNormal, vReflection));
        float fSpec = pow(spec, shininess) * lightSpecular.a;
        cf += intensity * vec3(fSpec) * lightSpecular.rgb * matSpecular.rgb;
    }

    // Color modulation
    vFragColor = vec4(ct * cf, at * af);

    // Add the fog to the mix
    if(fogEnabled) {
        vFragColor = mix(vFragColor, fogColor, fogFactor);
    }
}
```

What math bug could be causing this distortion?

### Edit 1:

I've updated the shader code. The attenuation is now being computed in the fragment shader, as it should have been all along. It's currently disabled, though - the bug doesn't have anything to do with the attenuation. When rendering *only* the attenuation factor of the light (see the last few lines of the fragment shader), the attenuation is being computed *right*. This means that the light position is being correctly transformed into eye coordinates, so it can't be the source of the bug.

The last few lines of the fragment shader can be used for some (slightly hackish but nevertheless insightful) debugging - it seems the intensity of the light is not being computed right per-fragment, though I have no idea why.

What's interesting is that this bug is only noticeable on (very) large quads like the floor in the images. It's not noticeable on small models.

### Edit 2:

I've updated the shader code to a working version. It's all good now and I hope it helps any future user reading this, since as of today, I have yet to see any glsl tutorial that implements lights with absolutely no fixed functionality and secret implicit transforms (such as `gl_LightSource[i].*` and the implicit transformations to eye space).

My code is licensed under the BSD 2-clause license and [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/AndreiBarsan/Yeti)!

Comment: May be it is because you do vertex based lightning whose quality depends on vertices amount.How many vertices do you have?Are those evenly distributed ? I would suggest phong shading in fragment shader.Also not sure you have to do this:  vec3 vPosition3 = vPosition4.xyz / vPosition4.w;

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but that *is* phong lighting - all the light computation is done in the fragment shader. The floor plane is just a single quad - if this were vertex lighting, no particular light shape would be visible projected on the floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem, where lighting worked somewhat wrong when using large polygons. The problem was normalizing the eye vector in vertex shader, as interpolating normalized values procudes incorrect results.

Change

```
vVaryingLightDir = normalize( tLightPos - vPosition3 );
```

to

```
vVaryingLightDir = tLightPos - vPosition3;
```

in your vertex shader. You can keep the normalization in the fragment shader.

Comment: Thanks you! This works perfectly now! But that must mean that the shader examples in the OpenGL SuperBible 5th ed. are wrong. :( (page 275 - they perform the normalization in the vertex shader) But mathematically, your explanation now makes a lot of sense - there would be no point in doing this normalization in the vertex shader! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just because I noticed:

```
vec3 tLightPos = (vMatrix * vec4(vLightPosition, 1.0)).xyz;
```

you are simply eliminating the homogenous coordinate here, without dividing through it first. This will cause some problems.